# How to create multiple ratio columns from existing columns? (R)

Tags: r

Let's say I have a dataframe with numeric columns named "a" through "z". I would like to create new columns which would be ratios of a given subset of columns, combining each single one against all the others in this subset. I should also mention that some of these columns have either zeros or missing values.

E.g.: if the subset consisted of columns "a" through "c", the new columns should be "a/b", "a/c", "b/a", "b/c", "c/a", "c/b". I would need to have these new columns added to my original dataframe.

How can I manage to get this?

I found a similar question here, but I could not get this solution to work (partly because in my case, I need to loop over a subset of the columns, not the whole dataframe):
[Loop to compute ratios of each column with n other columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46003581/loop-to-compute-ratios-of-each-column-with-n-other-columns)

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Appears that you only need a method to create the reversed pairings. Here it is:

```
> combn(z,2)
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,] "a"  "a"  "b" 
[2,] "b"  "c"  "c" 
> combn(rev(z),2)
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,] "c"  "c"  "b" 
[2,] "b"  "a"  "a"
```

The matrix with both results would be created with `cbind`

```
comb_ratios <-  cbind( combn(z,2), combn(rev(z),2) )
```

You should now make sure you have upvoted that earlier answer and then apply it to this matrix object. There should not be any difficulty with NA's and 0 as long as you can accept the `NA` and `Inf` results that will be returned. (And now reviewing that prior answer it appears to have been entirely on point, so I'm marking your question as a duplicate.)

Answer (score 0):

Here's an approach using the `tidyverse` package, where I join the data to itself, calculate the ratios, and reshape wide again to join to the original data:

First, I reshape the data longer to make the joining simpler.

```
mtcars_long <- mtcars %>%
  tibble::rownames_to_column("car") %>%
  pivot_longer(-car) 

# This now looks like:
## A tibble: 352 × 3
#   car       name   value
#   <chr>     <chr>  <dbl>
# 1 Mazda RX4 mpg    21   
# 2 Mazda RX4 cyl     6   
# 3 Mazda RX4 disp  160    
# ...
```

Now we can join it to itself to get all the ratio combinations. `mtcars` has 11 columns of numeric data, and 11 x 10 = 110 ratios. The table below has a column for car and the 110 ratios.

```
mtcars_ratios <- mtcars_long %>%
  left_join(mtcars_long, by = "car") %>%
  filter(name.x != name.y) %>%
  transmute(car,
            ratio_col = paste0(name.x, "/", name.y),
            ratio = value.x / value.y) %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = ratio_col, values_from = ratio)

# The top left of that table looks like:
# A tibble: 3 × 8
  car           `mpg/cyl` `mpg/disp` `mpg/hp` `mpg/drat` `mpg/wt` `mpg/qsec` `mpg/vs`
  <chr>             <dbl>      <dbl>    <dbl>      <dbl>    <dbl>      <dbl>    <dbl>
1 Mazda RX4           3.5      0.131    0.191       5.38     8.02       1.28    Inf  
2 Mazda RX4 Wag       3.5      0.131    0.191       5.38     7.30       1.23    Inf  
3 Datsun 710          5.7      0.211    0.245       5.92     9.83       1.23     22.8
```

We can add that onto the original data to get the augmented data frame. This produces a new table that is 121 columns wide, the top left of which looks like:

```
mtcars %>%
  bind_cols(mtcars_ratios[-1])


                   mpg cyl disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb  mpg/cyl   mpg/disp    mpg/hp mpg/drat   mpg/wt mpg/qsec mpg/vs mpg/am mpg/gear
Mazda RX4         21.0   6  160 110 3.90 2.620 16.46  0  1    4    4 3.500000 0.13125000 0.1909091 5.384615 8.015267 1.275820    Inf   21.0 5.250000
Mazda RX4 Wag     21.0   6  160 110 3.90 2.875 17.02  0  1    4    4 3.500000 0.13125000 0.1909091 5.384615 7.304348 1.233843    Inf   21.0 5.250000
Datsun 710        22.8   4  108  93 3.85 2.320 18.61  1  1    4    1 5.700000 0.21111111 0.2451613 5.922078 9.827586 1.225148   22.8   22.8 5.700000
Hornet 4 Drive    21.4   6  258 110 3.08 3.215 19.44  1  0    3    1 3.566667 0.08294574 0.1945455 6.948052 6.656299 1.100823   21.4    Inf 7.133333
Hornet Sportabout 18.7   8  360 175 3.15 3.440 17.02  0  0    3    2 2.337500 0.05194444 0.1068571 5.936508 5.436047 1.098707    Inf    Inf 6.233333
```